# Vuejs component not registering with laravel

Tags: laravel, vue.js

I know this question is being asked several times, but I couldn't find any solution to my problem.

I have two vue components on my laravel project. The first one is the laravel default component called "ExampleComponent.vue" and the second one is my own new component called "multi.vue".

I use them in a section.blade.php file like below:

```
@extends('layouts.app')

@section('content')
<example-component></example-component>

<multi></multi>

@endsection
```

but only the "example-component" works and for the "multi" component, it gives me the following error:

Unknown custom element:  - did you register the component correctly? For recursive components, make sure to provide the "name" option.

here is my app.js code:

```
require('./bootstrap');

window.Vue = require('vue');

Vue.component('example-component', require('./components/ExampleComponent.vue').default);

Vue.component('multi', require('./components/multi.vue').default);

const app = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
});
```

Here is my components codes:

ExampleComponent.vue:

```
<template>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row justify-content-center">
            <div class="col-md-8">
                <div class="card">
                    <div class="card-header">Example Component</div>

                    <div class="card-body">
                        I'm an example component.
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        mounted() {
            console.log('Component mounted.')
        }
    }
</script>
```

And my multi.vue:

```
<template>
  <div>
      I am multi component!
  </div>
</template>

<script>
   export default {
       mounted() {
           console.log('multi mounted.')
       }
   }
</script>

<style>

</style>
```

And the route is:

```
Route::get('/section',function(){
    return view('section');
});
```

Comment: Just to make sure, you _did_ run `npm run dev` (or `npm run watch`) after you created your component?

Comment: I ran `npm run dev`. it gave me the Failed to mount component: template or render function not defined error. But now I ran `npm run watch` and it seems that it's working!

Comment: The problem is about caching app.js, please try this:        
`<script src="{{ mix('/js/app.js') }}?v={{ time() }}" defer></script>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For solving this problem, all you need to do is to run "run npm watch".

After running that command, it will recomplie your vue code whenever you make a change in your code and save it.

Keep it in a separate terminal, and run "php artisan serve" in another terminal.

Answer (score 0):

From https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/style-guide/#Multi-word-component-names-essential:

> Component names should always be multi-word, except for root App
> components, and built-in components provided by Vue, such as
> `<transition>` or `<component>`.
>
> This prevents conflicts with existing and future HTML elements, since
> all HTML elements are a single word.

Comment: I tried renaming my component to "multi-component". looks like it's not a syntax or naming problem. Whenever I run "npm run watch", it works, but when I change the code, I need to run "npm run watch" again to update it. Also the "npm run dev" command causes the "Failed to mount component: template or render function not defined" error